# Send email to each user of a public group, queue, or related list

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-alert

Is there a way or workaround to send email individually to a user from a public group or queue?

My use case is I have a dynamic related list of users (dependent on the type of service that is impacted) that needs to be notify individually and not as a single email to the whole group.  On the email alert, when I choose a public group or queue using workflow rules, the system sends the email to everyone in the TO section of the email header.

I tried doing a field update base on a record change and update email field on the parent object but it work only to send the email to the first user of the lists.  Is there a way to do multiple field update from the list of users and send to each user individually?  Is this possible using Visual Flow?  I prefer this route as I am familiar with it.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: To clarify, here are the steps I would like to accomplish via Process Builder, Flow, and Workflow rule:
1.  Process Builder & Flow - iterate through a sobject collection variable of email addresses to do a field update to the email field trigger from a parent record change via Process Builder.
2.  Workflow Rule - send the email to the individual using workflow rule and clear the email field.
3.  Repeat step 1 and 2 until all email has been sent to each user of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish all of this via Process builder and flow, you don't need the workflow rule.
Have process builder populate a variable in your auto launched flow.
Populate your collection with the email list.
Use a Send email element in your flow with the contact as a variable. 
Have it loop that send email element replacing the contact in each iteration.

Great Flow Guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8kSMxoiWyk&t=326s

Comment: :D Happy to help!